# Serialize HTML form data to text file

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I created a form wizard using the [bootstrap application wizard](https://github.com/amoffat/bootstrap-application-wizard). My question is I want to take that data and do the following:

1. Export to an excel file to view immediately
2. Export to a text file

Here is a condensed version of my form:

```
 <div class="wizard" id="CR-wizard" style="color: #030845" data-title="CRITSIT Wizard">

                <!--Step 1-->
                <div class="wizard-card" data-cardname="name">
                    <h3>Contact Information</h3>
                    <div class="wizard-input-section">
                        <p>Full Name</p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control" id="Name" style="width: 220px"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

  <div class="wizard-input-section">
                        <p>Application Manager</p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="AppManager" name="AppManager" placeholder="CATIA, ENOVIA, DELMIA..." style="width: 220px" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wizard-input-section">
                        <p>Focal or Project Manager</p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="AppFocal" name="AppFocal" placeholder="Application Focal" style="width: 220px" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wizard-input-section">
                        <p>Supplier</p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SuppFocal" name="SuppFocal" placeholder="Supplier Focal" style="width: 220px" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

  <div class="wizard-input-section">
                        <p>Version:</p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Version" placeholder="Version #" name="Version" style="width: 220px" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wizard-input-section">
                        <p>Requested Software Level:</p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Level" name="Level" placeholder="Software Level" style="width: 220px" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wizard-input-section">
                        <p>Requested Release Designator:</p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ReleaseDesignator" name="ReleaseDesignator" placeholder="Designator" style="width: 220px" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

And here is the javascript that will control opening, submitting and closing the wizard:

```
  wizard.on('closed', function () {
                wizard.reset();
            });

            wizard.on("reset", function () {
                wizard.modal.find(':input').val('').removeAttr('disabled');
                wizard.modal.find('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-succes');
                wizard.modal.find('#fqdn').data('is-valid', 0).data('lookup', 0);
            });

            wizard.on("submit", function (wizard) {
                var submit = {
                    "hostname": $("#new-server-fqdn").val()
                };

                this.log('seralize()');
                this.log(this.serialize());
                this.log('serializeArray()');
                this.log(this.serializeArray());
                setTimeout(function () {
                    wizard.trigger("success");
                    wizard.hideButtons();
                    wizard._submitting = false;
                    wizard.showSubmitCard("success");
                    wizard.updateProgressBar(0);
                }, 2000);
            });

            wizard.el.find(".wizard-success .im-done").click(function () {
                wizard.hide();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    wizard.reset();
                }, 250);

            });

            wizard.el.find(".wizard-success .create-another-server").click(function () {
                wizard.reset();
            });

            $(".wizard-group-list").click(function () {
                alert("Disabled for demo.");
            });

            $(document).ready('#open-wizard()');
            {
                wizard.show();
            }

            $('#open-wizard').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                wizard.show();
            });
```

Really kind of new to using javascript and html forms and when I did research I found mostly answers using PHP and in my case I am using asp.net and c# to accomplish this.

Any help on how to go about this would be great!

Comment: How much work have you done in C#? One path would be to setup a WCF REST service that will receive your POST as a stream and the handle it appropriately. [MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751463.aspx)

Comment: @Infinitesimus, I have a good understanding of c#. I will look into this method. thank you!

Comment: Great! I've added an answer with a few more links to get you started. Just be wary about the kind of reader you use for the stream if you're handling binary data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) service to handle it for you. [(Tutorial)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You should use a service format similar to this:

```
namespace MyServive
{
    public class FileConverter : IFIleConverter
    {
       public double Add(stream rawdata)
         {
           //write to files
         }
    }
}
```

The important piece is that you are expecting a stream. Read some more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx).

The basic idea is that you want a service operation that accepts a **stream**. When you have this stream, it is the responsibility of your code to properly write it to file based on your desired encoding. Be aware that if you're handling excel files (or binary data in general), a using a `StreadReader` will probably not handle the data properly since it isn't designed for binary data.